# Selecting radio button dynamically in ionic 4

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic4

[image] 
I have a modal that i am having data to populate from the parent page. and in the modal i have group radio button for sex and i am having difficulties in getting the right gender checked from my data and how to get the change gender

**Edits**
i am getting female on the default screen checked and whenever i clicked for the first time on the male radio button the value will change to true and on 3rd attempt the male will be checked without unchecking the the female...

### .ts

```
public data: any = {
  sex: 'Male',
};
```

## HTML

```
<ion-radio-group>
  <!-- <ion-item> -->
    <ion-radio value="Female"  [(ngModel)]="data.sex" [checked]="this.data.sex==='Female'" name="sex" id="male" id="female"></ion-radio>
          &nbsp;&nbsp;
      <ion-label for="female">Female</ion-label>
          &nbsp;&nbsp;
    <ion-radio value="Male"  [(ngModel)]="data.sex"  name="sex" [checked]="this.data.sex==='Male'" id="male"></ion-radio> &nbsp;&nbsp;
      <ion-label for="male">Male</ion-label>
  <!-- </ion-item> -->
</ion-radio-group>
```

Comment: Don't you just need to remove `this` keyword from `checked` attribute?

Answer (score 6):

I try a different approach to your problem. Instead of using a two-way data binding `[(ngModel)]`, I've used `(ionChange)` which is an EventEmitter.

`(ionChange)` will detect any changes and pass the event to the `onChangeHandler($event)`. Every time the function was triggered, the value from the event will be extracted replacing the value inside the object `data.sex`.

Lastly, property binding was used to directly access the elements property of `[checked]` to dynamically check the `ion-radio` based on the `data.sex` value.

**TS**

```
  public data: any = {
    sex: 'Male'
  };


  onChangeHandler($event) {
    this.data.sex = $event.target.value;
  }
```

**HTML**

```
  <ion-radio-group (ionChange)="onChangeHandler($event)">
    <ion-item>
      <ion-label>Male</ion-label>
      <ion-radio value="Male" [checked]="this.data.sex==='Male'"></ion-radio>
    </ion-item>
    <ion-item>
      <ion-label>Female</ion-label>
      <ion-radio value="Female" [checked]="this.data.sex==='Female'"></ion-radio>
    </ion-item>
  </ion-radio-group>
  <p>{{this.data.sex}}</p>
```

[Show result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HA3O3.gif)

Comment: Can you please explain what you did so others can learn from your answer? (thx)

Comment: @elbrant Sorry about that, I've added some explanation to my answer.